# Householder QR factorization for banded matrices

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to use **Householder QR factorization** for triangularization of **banded matrices** with a lower band and upper band. So, I modified the QR Householder algorithm for the lower band but can't get to a modification of the algorithm for the upper band to work. Here below, for the lower band I take the x array to only where it's non-zero. That takes care of the HH reflector. Then, when updating A, it updates a rectangular array which takes zeros from the upper band (which I would like to ignore). I've tried to vectorize that part (ignoring the zeros of the upper band) but can't get it to work. Any thoughts?

% HH QR algorithm, Trefethen. I modified it to take advantage of the lower band. **To be clear, the algorithm posted works. I'm looking for an improvement so that it can take advantage of the upper band, too**.

A is mxn; Banded with lower band (*lowband*) and upper band (*upperband*).

```
for k = n
    kl = min(k+lowband, m); Here taking care of lower band
    x = A(k:kl,k);
    e = zeros(length(x),1); e(1) = 1;
    u = sign(x(1))*norm(x)*e + x;
    u = u/norm(u);
    % For A notice only taking advantage of lower band
    A(k:kl, k:n) = A(k:kl, k:n) - 2*u*u'*A(k:kl, k:n); % update A to lower triang
end
```

Comment: Index error in line 3, should be $R(k:k+kl)$. The same error is present in the second to last line.

Comment: That's not an error. It's correct. The algorithm posted works. I'm looking for an improvement.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I read $kl$ with the eyes of $LAPACK$. Look at you end result. Did the upper bandwidth grow?

Comment: Np. Well, the one above does not take into consideration the upper bandwidth at all; it's just including the lower one.

Comment: In that case, only a *small* set of column in front of the current diagonal position need be updated. Try to draw the sparsity pattern of, say, a pentadiagonal matrix and symbolically execute the updates.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it's not exact because you lose some nonzero rows. Notice that the algorithm selects the A update rectangularly (i.e. A(k:kl, k:n) ) and in the upper portion you will have zeros but not for the lower portion of the selection (e.g. of a pentadiagonal matrix). Now, I've thought about a few things but let me not bias your train of thought.